# Add AAD application as an owner of AAD group programmatically

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application in Azure Active Directory.

[image]

What permission is required to add this application as an owner of a (M365) group in Azure Active Directory programmatically?

[image]

Comment: You need `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission to add application as an owner of a (M365) group in Azure Active Directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have M365 group named **Sri Team** with properties like below:

[image]

I registered one Azure AD application named `test-user-app` as below:

[image]

> To add this application as an **owner** of a (M365) group in Azure
> Active Directory via Graph API, you need `Group.ReadWrite.All`
> permission.

You can get the **Object ID** of above service principal from *Enterprise Applications* like below:

[image]

I ran below query in **[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)** and got **response** like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupID>/owners/$ref/

{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals/<objectID>"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

I granted consent to `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission under **Modify permissions** before running query like this:

[image]

When I checked in Portal, application added successfully as **owner** of M365 group like below:

[image]

To do the same from **PowerShell**, you can make use of below script:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Group.ReadWrite.All"

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Groups

$groupId = "b70fc9f0-2c7e-4e8a-b4cd-xxxxxxxxxx"
$params = @{
    "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals/ObjectID"
}

New-MgGroupOwnerByRef -GroupId $groupId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

To do the same in React/TypeScript application, modify your `MsGraphApiCall.ts` file by changing **graph API query** and including request body with `POST` method like below:

```js
export async function callMsGraph() {
    const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
    if (!account) {
        throw Error("No active account! Verify a user has been signed in and setActiveAccount has been called.");
    }

    const response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
        ...loginRequest,
        account: account
    });

    const headers = new Headers();
    const requestBody = {'@odata.id':'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals/ObjectID'};
    
    const bearer = `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`;
    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    };

    return fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupID>/owners/$ref/", options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please let me know how to do in React/TypeScript application?

Comment: You can check the **updated** answer for React/TypeScript application.

Comment: can I use any other permission to achieve the same other than Group.ReadWrite.All/ Directory.ReadWrite.All ?

Comment: No, you can only assign Group.ReadWrite.All/ Directory.ReadWrite.All to add owner of group. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).