# minimal application permission to delete a group using MS Graph

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I can delete and update Groups using the MS Graph API just fine. But when I try to remove one, I'm consistently getting this:

`Authorization_RequestDenied - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`

Looking through the MS documentation, they say in an app-only scenario, I need this:

> For app-only scenarios, the calling app must be the owner of the group or be assigned the RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory application permission or be assigned the Global Administrator or Privileged Role Administrator Azure AD role.

So, I assigned the `RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory` permission to my app registration, and granted admin consent. Waited 1 Microsoft, then tried again only to get the same error. Sure, I could just make my app Global Admin, but that ain't going to fly anywhere but on a dev environment. (note - I also have `Group.ReadWrite.All` - using it to create and update groups)
So, what am I missing here? I'm open to trying to setting my app registration as owner.. but the owner examples in the documentation only mentions users..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created one **role-assignable** group named **`RAgroup`** like below:

[image]

Now, I registered one Azure AD application and granted below **API permissions**:

[image]

I generated access token using **client credentials** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appID
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below graph query to delete that group, I got **same error** as you:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission is required to delete
> groups. But if the group is **role assignable**, additional permission is
> required as mentioned in this [**MS Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions)

To **resolve** the error, I assigned application as **owner** of the group like below:

[image]

After assigning application as **group owner**, it will be displayed like this after few minutes:

[image]

When I ran below graph query by generating **token again**, I got below response:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal by refreshing page where group deleted successfully like below:

[image]

In my case, assigning `RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory` permission of **Application** type also worked.

[image]

After adding above permission, generate the token again and decode it by pasting in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) to check permissions:

[image]

Comment: I'm creating the group through MS graph directly, so how do you assign the app registration as owner through MS graph?  I can assign user owners just fine using
[example 2 in the doc][1], but it only mentions users.


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: You can refer this [**SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989562/add-aad-application-as-an-owner-of-aad-group-programmatically/75992054#75992054) that I previously answered to know how to add app registration as group owner. You need to pass `"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals/<objectID>"` in owners@odata.bind field.

Comment: Still having issues with the owner. This is what I'm sending

    {
     "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
     "owners@odata.bind": [
      "@odata.id: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals/<objectId of application>",
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id of user1>",
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id of user2>"
     ],
     "displayName": "Members CallGroup cqgroup1",
     "groupTypes": [
      "Unified"
     ],
     "mailEnabled": true,
     "securityEnabled": false,
    }

Comment: I guess you are passing Object ID of **app registration** in `"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals/<objectID>"`. But you should pass Object ID of **service principal** that can be found in _Enterprise applications_ like [this](https://i.imgur.com/QeuOxsX.png). There will be delay of few minutes to appear under Group owners tab after performing above operation.

Comment: ahh, I was looking at objectId of 'Application Registration', not 'Enterprise Applications'. Here's the working create
    {
 "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
 "owners@odata.bind": [
  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals/<objectid of enterprise app>",
  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<objectId>"
 ],
 "description": "Contains member of CallGroup cqgroup1",
 "displayName": "Members CallGroup cqgroup1",
 "groupTypes": [
  "Unified"
 ],
 "mailEnabled": true,
 "mailNickname": "cqgroup1",
 "securityEnabled": false,
 "visibility": "Private"
    }